# Docker daemon recently takes over 1 min to start - why?

Tags: linux, docker, fedora

## Problem

The Docker systemd daemon takes over a minute to start on my Fedora 27 laptop. This was not always the case – I first noticed the slowdown about 1-2 months ago. How can I speed up the Docker daemon start time?

## Analysis

I looked at the logs for the Docker engine, but it wasn't helpful. There's a large window where it doesn't seem like anything is happening.

```
# journalctl -fu docker
Jan 23 15:10:05 fossbook.justinwflory.com systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jan 23 15:11:35 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:35.830665755-05:00" level=warning msg="devmapper: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Please use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `man docker` to refer to dm.thinpooldev section."
Jan 23 15:11:35 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:35.869370589-05:00" level=warning msg="devmapper: Base device already exists and has filesystem xfs on it. User specified filesystem  will be ignored."
Jan 23 15:11:35 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:35.885762067-05:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: devicemapper"
Jan 23 15:11:35 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:35.893578695-05:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Jan 23 15:11:35 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:35.894872003-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Jan 23 15:11:35 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:35.895330760-05:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Jan 23 15:11:35 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:35.896277400-05:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jan 23 15:11:35 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:35.917175821-05:00" level=info msg="Firewalld running: true"
Jan 23 15:11:36 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:36.695388606-05:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Jan 23 15:11:36 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:36.961050250-05:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jan 23 15:11:36 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:36.975477466-05:00" level=warning msg="failed to retrieve docker-init version: unknown output format: tini version 0.16.1\n"
Jan 23 15:11:36 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:36.976280875-05:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jan 23 15:11:36 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:36.976323468-05:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=caba767-unsupported graphdriver=devicemapper version=1.13.1
Jan 23 15:11:36 fossbook.justinwflory.com dockerd-current[20839]: time="2018-01-23T15:11:36.993394464-05:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Jan 23 15:11:36 fossbook.justinwflory.com systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
```

I'm not aware of other helpful information to help me debug this. I know past behavior was almost instantaneous – this seems like a regression or a configuration error.

## How to debug?

I'm not sure how to debug this correctly because the logs are unhelpful. Is there more detailed information I can get on startup? How can I figure out what's taking so long?

Comment: How many containers are you running and how long do they each take to start?

Comment: @BMitch The containers usually start up quickly. But when I start the daemon, I don't have any containers running yet. It's only an issue with starting the Docker daemon.

Comment: Just to verify, no containers are configured with a restart policy? How many containers are there including stopped ones (`docker ps -a`)? How many networks are defined? How many volumes are defined?

Comment: Where you part of a Swarm that is no longer accessible? It might be some network component.

Comment: @goetzc I've never used Docker Swarm on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

To get more logging information, enable debugging.

Create or edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, make sure this key is present:

```
{
  "debug": true
}
```

Reload Docker daemon service `sudo systemctl reload docker` or if systemd is not installed, `sudo kill -SIGHUP $(pidof dockerd)`.

https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#enable-debugging

Comment: Oops, I forgot I had asked this question. I think the problem described in this original question is triggered by the same thing in [my Unix StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447836/unable-to-pull-from-any-docker-registry-when-selinux-is-enabled) about Docker troubles. Not only am I unable to pull images, but the daemon is still incredibly slow to start. I've done this step (enabling debugging) in that Unix StackExchange question.

Comment: Possibly related: see [this Red Hat Bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1585802) with my issue. As of now, it is still unsolved.